# How to call the controller to VF page with parameter

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, community

How to call the controller to VF page with parameter?I have two Visual force pages, and two controllers

**VF Page:DEMO**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="NewAndExistingController" id="demoId" >
    <apex:pageBlock >
     <br> </br>
 <apex:outputField value="{!a.Id}"/> <br> </br>
      </apex:pageBlock>
       <apex:form >

          <apex:pageBlock >
               <apex:commandButton value="Call visualforce Page" action="{!click}"/> 
          </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

**VF page:XYZ**

```
<apex:page standardController="Order__c" extensions="MyOrderPadController" >
    <apex:detail />
        <apex:form > 

        <apex:pageBlock >

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" value="Edit"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!reset}" value="Cancel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>


            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Order Pad">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Order_Description__c}"  />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Creat_Date__c}"  />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Closed_Date__c}"  />
                     <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Conformation__c}"  />  


            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```

**Controller:NewAndExistingController**

```
public class NewAndExistingController {
Public Account a{get;set;}public String accId;    public NewAndExistingController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    try{    a =[select id,name,accountnumber,annualrevenue from account where id=:controller.getId()];    MyOrderPadController.staticVar =a.Id;   
 }catch(exception e){}   
 }       
  public PageReference click() {      
  PageReference openvfpage = New Pagereference('/apex'+'/XYZ);     openvfpage.setRedirect(false);  return openvfpage ;        }    public NewAndExistingController() {    }  
 }
```

**Controller: MyOrderPadController**

```
  public class MyOrderPadController {  
      public Order__c order{ get; private set; 
    }     
       public static  String staticVar;   
        public String instanceVar {get; set;}   
            NewAndExistingController  test = new NewAndExistingController ();   
            public MyOrderPadController ()       {  
              instanceVar = staticVar;       
    }   
     public MyOrderPadController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) { 
           order = (Order__c)sc.getRecord();       
    }
    public PageReference edit()      {  
              return null;            
     }    
     public PageReference reset() {       
       PageReference newpage = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());          newpage.setRedirect(true);        
      return newpage; 
       }   
      public PageReference save()   
       {       
       TRY          {           
                      order.Name = 'Demo Test Order '+order.Order_Description__c;               order.Order_Description__c =order.Order_Description__c+':====>'+staticVar ;                order.Account__c = '0019000000NAr7bAAD';//for testing only                            IF(order.Conformation__c == TRUE){                                   
               INSERT order;                     PageReference newpage = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());                    newpage.setRedirect(true);                    return newpage;           
                  }                                                            }                       catch(System.DMLException e)           {   
             ApexPages.addMessages(e);            SYSTEM.DEBUG('ERROR ORDER PAD CONTROLLER :'+e);            return null;          }        //  After Save, navigate to the default view page:        //return (new ApexPages.StandardController(order)).view();        return null;             }   }
```

The  "DEMO" VF page added to Account under the one section ,As of  now I am getting  Account Id in the controller "NewAndExistingController" .This controller again called to the VF page "XYZ" .How to access this Account id in controller "MyOrderPadController".Right now it is hard coded,Once it get I remved.

I want get account id in the "MyOrderPadController" Any idea please share with me.

Regards,
Ramesh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In NewAndExistingController try adding a.id to Pagereference

```
PageReference openvfpage = New Pagereference('/apex'+'/XYZ+'?aid='+a.id);
```

You can refer this in the other controller as

```
order.Account__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('aid');
```

Comment: Hi I written public PageReference click() {
    
    PageReference openvfpage = New Pagereference('/apex'+'/orderpad'+'?aid='+a.id);
   
  openvfpage.setRedirect(false);
  return openvfpage ;
    
   }