# How to pass parameters from one VF page to another?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two VF pages and I want to pass one parameter from one VF page and get that parameter on another VF page through controller so,what should I do and also how to use POST Method for this purpose??

Comment: did you already try something ?

Comment: I tried this in VF like setting parameter using  <apex:param> tagg & getting that value in apex using                                          string passedParam1 = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myParam'); , but still its not working..

Answer (score 5):

You can simply pass the parameters through the URL.

say you are redirecting from one VF page to another

```
string value = 'your param value';
string url;
url = '/apex/VF_Page_Name?param1=' + value; 

PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(url);
pageRef.setRedirect(true);
return pageRef;
```

Then in the controller of the VF page, you just can get the param like this

```
String param_value = system.CurrentPageReference.GetParameters().get('param1');
```

Comment: Can you try this I think it helps  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22876/how-to-call-the-controller-to-vf-page-with-parameter

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
PageReference page = Page.secondPage;

page.getParameters().put('REPLEACE FOR KEY', 'REPLACE FOR VALUE');

return page;
```