# how to pass the value of output field to another page in salesforce apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a output field like

```
<apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.AccountNumber} "/>
```

and i want the value of this field(whisch is 1234Ex) to be passed to another page so that i can use it there.

Could you please help i could pass the value and how i need to use it in apex code?

Please help.Its urgent

Comment: Use same Controller for both pages.

Comment: You've shared very little information and no code, so people are going to struggle to help you.  Try [this similar question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36408/how-to-pass-parameters-from-one-vf-page-to-another).

Comment: <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.AccountNumber} "/>

I want to pas the value of this field to new page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the new page is a Visualforce page you can explicitly pass a parameter in the new page URL:

```
<apex:outputLink
        value="{!URLFOR($Page.SecondPage, null, [an=objAccount.AccountNumber])}"
        >Go to Second Page</apex:outputLink>
```

that the second page can then pick up:

```
public with sharing SecondPageController {

    private String accountNumber;

    public SecondPageController() {
        accountNumber = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('an');
    }

    // Other code can reference accountNumber
}
```

This pattern avoids an unnecessary round trip to the server.

Answer (score 0):

if you want pass a value from visualforce to another visualforce you can send the new value as Parameter URL.

**visualforce**

```
<apex:outputText value="acc.Name"/>
<apex:commandLink action="{!gotoNewPage}/>
```

**Controller**

```
public Account acc {get;set;}

public PageReference gotoNewPage(){
    PageReference newPage = Page.NewPage;
    newPage.getParameters.put('accName',acc.Name);
    return newPage;
}
```